# Test case count report in testlink

Tags: testlink

Test link reports seem highly tied with a test plan. I have test cases marked with "Execution Type" manual / automated. I just could not find any way to gather count of manual and automated tests with out creating a test plan.

Is any one else collecting such metrics from test link without involving test plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not, since, in theory you can not start executing test cases until you have some kind of a test plan in place. Not to say that it doesn't happen. I have worked in a couple of projects where we were asked to create and start executing test cases without any prior design/plan.

If it's just the count of test cases you need, you can get the "total" count from the Test Specification page. Data in reports will only be generated if you execute your test cases on Testlink. You will only be able to execute test cases if you specify a test plan.

Comment: I guess I need to go to test specification and plot some graphs on my own. This is close to what I was looking for.